# Lodash filter with limit

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way to filter the first n elements from an array that match a criteria?

I know you can `filter` and then call `take` but doesn't that go through the whole list instead of exiting after reaching the limit?

```
_(books).filter(function(book) {return book.pages > 10}).take(5).value();
```

Comment: What is the isuse with it going through the list?  If you're trying to take 5 from 1000's of records, you should probably try to limit the data that's coming back before you try and optimize your array filtering.  Or if it is that important, wrap your own iterator and break out of it when the condition is met.

Comment: @VtoCorleone do you have an example of wrapping your own iterator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the iterator function passed to the `_.forEach()` function returns `false`, the iteration is stopped immediately.

The following `filter` function illustrates how `_.forEach()` can be used to solve your use case.

```js
function filter(books, maxCount) {
  var results = [];
  _.forEach(books, function(book) {
    if (results.length === maxCount) {
      return false;
    }
    if (book.pages > 10) {
      results.push(book);
    }
  });
  return results;
}


var N = 5;
var books = new Array(20);

// Give each book a page count equal to its books index.
_.forEach(books, function(v, i) {books[i] = {pages: i}});

console.log(filter(books, N));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is great for almost all cases, except when you have to process a huge amount of data. Can't think of a more efficient lodash solution, but this would suffice:

```
var take = 5;
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  var book = books[i];
  if(book.pages > 10) {
    result.push(book);
    --take;
  }
  if(take === 0) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: copied your decrementation pattern as its more readable on how much to take +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
var limit = 5,
    result = [];
_.forEach(books, function(book) {
    if (limit--) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (book.pages > 10) {
            result.push(book);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should add a citation of the answer from which you "copied" this pattern. Also, explanation of how the code helps the user is almost always a good idea.

Comment: ... Not sure what you're talking about. But you already said, in your comment in the other answer, that you copied it. Under the CC-by-SA license, you have to give attribution to the other user. But whatevs, lulz.

Comment: i was being nice to OP. I did not copy anything. look at my edit history.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is only one lodash function that allows you to terminate early, which is [_.transform](https://lodash.com/docs#transform).

```js
result = _(books).transform(function(result, book) {
 book.pages > 10 && result.push(book);
 return result.length < 5;
}).value();

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/4.15.0/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var books = [
    { title: 'a', pages: 8 },
    { title: 'b', pages: 10 },
    { title: 'c', pages: 12 },
    { title: 'd', pages: 14 },
    { title: 'e', pages: 16 },
    { title: 'f', pages: 5 },
    { title: 'g', pages: 18 },
    { title: 'h', pages: 20 }
  ]
</script>
```

Ofcourse, you can create your own API as well using a mixin:

```js
// define mixin once somewhere:
_.mixin({'findWhile': function(collection, predicate, num) {
  return _.transform(collection, function(result, value) {
    predicate(value) && result.push(value);
    return result.length < num;
  });
}});

// then to use it:
var result = _(books).findWhile(function(book) { return book.pages > 10 }, 5).value();

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/4.15.0/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var books = [
    { title: 'a', pages: 8 },
    { title: 'b', pages: 10 },
    { title: 'c', pages: 12 },
    { title: 'd', pages: 14 },
    { title: 'e', pages: 16 },
    { title: 'f', pages: 5 },
    { title: 'g', pages: 18 },
    { title: 'h', pages: 20 }
  ]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    book.pages.push(page);
    if(book.pages.length > WHATEVER){
        book.pages = _.drop(book.pages, book.pages.length - WHATEVER );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const length = 5;
_.slice(books, length + 1);
```

Using [ARRAY SLICE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) / [LoDASH SLICE](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#slice) you can easily limit the array via length

Here the length limit is 5, you need to add (*+1*), because array index starts from zero (*0*)

Answer (score -1):

You can just set the length of an array

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

if (numbers.length > 3) {
    numbers.length = 3;
}

console.log(numbers); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(numbers.length); // 3
```

See [MDN webdocs Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to make `filter()` exit once the limit has been reached, in order to avoid an expensive performance cost. It seems like you're just showing how to truncate the array _after_ that expensive operation has already been performed.